# How to determine which element to display based on whether it and others have content

Tags: php, css

I have four elements on a page, elements 1 - 4 in that order selectable to view by CSS tabs.  These elements are part of user profiles.

Element 1: About Me
Element 2: Interests
Element 3: Online
Element 4: Statistics

I build these elements based on whether users have added this information into their profiles and store the elements in variables:

```
$aboutme
$interests
$online
```

All users have statistics so there is no variable for that content.

The tabs on a user profile that show are based on whether there is content in the respective element.

So if there is About Me and Online content, three tabs will show, About Me, Online and Statistics.

Now I need to figure out which element to initally display.

For example, if About Me only has content, initially only About Me should be visible and the other three should not be visible.

If Interests and Online have content then initially Interests should only be visible and the other three should not be visible.

If About Me, Interests and Online have no content then initially Statistics should be made visible.

I am having a mental block figuring out the logic here.

Site coded in PHP.

Comment: is the content dynamically loaded into the page? If so, can you provide some code you already have? And I assume you want to do this server side?

Comment: Yes it is.  I have three variables with content, let's say $element1, $element2, $element3.  4 always has content.  If 2 and 3 have content, then 2 should be visible and 1, 3 and 4 should not be visible.  If 1 has content, 2, 3 and 4 should not be visible.  And if 1-3 do not have content then 1-3 should not be visible and 4 should be visible.  Not sure if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make *the first element that has content* visible. It's guaranteed that at least one element will (element 4 if no other).

For example, if we have

```
$vars = array(0, 0, 1, 1);
```

and we need to find the index of first array element that is equal to `1`, we 'd do:

```
foreach($vars as $key => $value) {
    if($value != 0) {
        $index = $key;
        break;
    }
}

// Now $index is 2 (3rd element)
```

A specific solution would depend on how and in what kind of variable your content for the elements is stored, but I believe it won't be difficult to implement it yourself.

Comment: If I do something like this though: if ($element1 != "") {$element1visible = true; } else { $element1visible = false; } if ($element2 != "") {$element2visible = true; } else { $element2visible = false; } then if elements 1 and 2 have content, they will both be visible, I would only want element 1 to be visible.

Comment: @Tom: You need to learn to use arrays for that kind of thing. Having variables `$element1`, `$element2`, ..., `$element42` is not the way to go.

Comment: Using that naming convention was probably not the way to go for this exercise.  The real application of this is I have user profiles with sections.  The sections are About Me, Interests, Online and Statistics.  User profiles will always have statistics but the other sections are dependent on whether the user adds that content to their profile.  So I build those sections into string variables, $aboutme, $interests and $online.  These sections are tabs across a page that are visible based on whether there is content.  As a user clicks each tab, I show the applicable content.  Now I just can't...

Comment: ...figure out how to initially display the content.

Comment: @Tom: Then update the question to show what you have -- and please don't be stingy.

Comment: Yeah, I was really stingy now that I think about it, thanks, updated with much more detail.

Comment: Oh man, you are a life saver.  This is one of those simple things that just racked my brain for some reason.  Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$elements = array($aboutme, $interests, $online, $statistics);
$initially_visible = '';

foreach($elements as $key => $val) {
   if(!empty($val)) {
     $initially_visible = $key;
     break;
   }
}

foreach($elements as $key => $val) {
   echo ($initially_visible == $key) ? '<div class="visible">' : '<div class="hidden">';
   echo $val.'</div>';
}
?>
```